# What's the canonical "how do I downgrade?" question?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Today we got this one:

- [How to downgrade Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106614/how-to-downgrade-ubuntu)

Which I knew was a dupe, but we have a bunch of these:

- [downgrading ubuntu from 11.10 to 10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94872/downgrading-ubuntu-from-11-10-to-10-04)
- [Downgrade Ubuntu 11.10 to older release (8.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77644/downgrade-ubuntu-11-10-to-older-release-8-10)

This one actually seems to be the best one, should we just generalize this one and point them all there since no matter what the version is it's always going to be the same answer?

- [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-11-10-to-11-04)

Answer (score 4):

Yes definitely. A general answer could cover all those questions.

I have changed the title of the question last linked question (it already has a very good answer) and removed the versions tags, we should mark possible duplicates and point them there.

I suggest we make the answer there community wiki and give a nice bounty to the user that posted the answer (like if he needs any more!).

That should allow us to point all dupes to that one.

Comment: Might also want to consider whether some answer should be merged in.